# Importing an array into mainActivity class from a method of another class

Tags: java

I have a custom class with the following code

```
public class BeerExpert {
public String[] getBrands(String color){
    String[] beer_brands= new String[2];
    if(color=="light") {
        beer_brands[0]="Budwiser";
        beer_brands[1]="Corona";
    }
    return beer_brands;

}
}
```

I want to import the list of array "beer_brands" in the other class, which is my mainActivity.java class.
How ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access beer_brands in another class.

In the other class, use the following (in any method):

```
BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
String[] beer_brands = be.getBrands("light");
```

All this does is create an instance of the class, and then call "getBrands()" using that instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the `getBrands()` method directly from your `MainActivity` class then you just have to reference the array returned from the function in your `MainActivity` class. Here is how you can do it:

```
BeerExpert beerExpert = new BeerExpert();
String[] beer_brands = beerExpert.getBrands("light");
```

If you are not calling the `getBrands()` method from `MainActivity` class but from some other class and am only interested in the array declared in `BeerActivity` class then you'll have to declare it as `static` in your `BeerExpert` class:

```
public class BeerExpert {

    /* Public Static */
    public static String[] beer_brands = new String[2];

    public String[] getBrands(String color){

        if(color=="light") {
            beer_brands[0]="Budwiser";
            beer_brands[1]="Corona";
        }
        return beer_brands;

    }

}
```

You can then import it as follows in your `MainActivity` class:

```
String[] beer_brands = BeerExpert.beer_brands;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use `equals()`, compares the value equality means string values.

`==` compares object references.

```
    if(color.equals("light")) {
        beer_brands[0]="Budwiser";
        beer_brands[1]="Corona";
    }
```

**Refrence:** [compare strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

2.To access `beer_brands` array in `mainActivity` class, just return the result from `getBrands()`method of `BeerExpert` class.

In `mainActivity` class,

```
BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
String[] beer_brands = be.getBrands("light");
```